# I am not able to redirect to other website URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following controller

> Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::SessionsController

with action,

```
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.errors.empty?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
  end
end
```

Protected method `after_confirmation_path` to redirect,

```
protected
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
   flash[:notice] = "Your account was successfully confirmed. Please sign  in using the mobile application."
   redirect_to "http://referd.net"
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question? What is error log?

Answer (score 0):

In your `show` action instead of overriding `after_confirmation_path_for` directly `redirect` to other url like this.

```
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
  if resource.errors.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "Your account was successfully confirmed. Please sign  in using the mobile application."
    redirect_to "http://referd.net"
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem was with the AbstractController::DoubleRenderError , now it is working.

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::SessionsController

    def show
      self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.errors.empty?
        respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
      else
        respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
      end
    end
    protected

    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      flash[:notice] = "Your account was successfully confirmed. Please sign in using the mobile application."
      **"http://referd.net"**
    end
end
```